# @DenyAll ignored with Jersey (JAX-RS)

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Here is my resource

```
@Path("test")
@DenyAll
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response test() {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("ok").build();
    }
}
```

When I run the application and call GET /test the response is sent.
I am kind of confused, is there something else to do in addition to the annotation? Am I supposed to deny access myself in a filter?
When I use `@RolesAllowed()` I don't have to implement anything...

Thanks.

Comment: Did you register the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`?

Comment: Yes I did, the annotation ```@RolesAllowed()``` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for [`RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.java#L85), you will see two two thing:

1. `DenyAll` is never checked for on classes.
2. There is a [comment](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.java#L110) `// DenyAll can't be attached to classes`

Comment: Ok, it works only at the method level. I guess I got confused by some JAX-RS tutorials/blog posts. Thanks.